# Any closed formula for this summation involving binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am stuck with writing a closed formula for the following summation:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-m} (-1)^i {m \choose i} {n-m \choose i}^2$$

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This looks like an hypergeometric function ... which is not "exactly" a closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-m} (-1)^i {m \choose i} {n-m \choose i}^2=\, _3F_2(-m,m-n,m-n;1,1;1)$$ where appears the generalized hypergeometric function which is not a closed form. I do not see any way to simplify it.

If you fix $m$, you will get a polynomial in $n$ of degree $2m$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & \, _3F_2(-m,m-n,m-n;1,1;1) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -n^2 +2n\\
 2 & \frac{n^4}{4}-\frac{5 n^3}{2}+\frac{29 n^2}{4}-7 n+2 \\
 3 & -\frac{n^6}{36}+\frac{2 n^5}{3}-\frac{211 n^4}{36}+\frac{145 n^3}{6}-\frac{893
   n^2}{18}+\frac{146 n}{3}-18 \\
 4 & \frac{n^8}{576}-\frac{11 n^7}{144}+\frac{389 n^6}{288}-\frac{113
   n^5}{9}+\frac{38785 n^4}{576}-\frac{30869 n^3}{144}+\frac{6365
   n^2}{16}-\frac{791 n}{2}+162
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Many thanks Claude!